# RestAssured: chunked file upload instead of multipart

Tags: spring-mvc, file-upload, rest-assured

### Problem

I have a controller with the signature

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/upload/{imageTitle}", method = POST, produces = {APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity<EnrollFaceResult> uploadImage(@PathVariable String imageTitle, ServletInputStream imageDataStream) {
    // handle upload
}
```

Now I want to test the logic using [RestAssured](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured):

```
    given()
        .pathParam("imageTitle", "title")
        .multiPart(new File(getClass().getResource("image.jpg").toURI()))
    .when()
        .post("upload/{imageTitle}")
    .then()
        .statusCode(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK)
```

The problem is that there is no data in the `imageDataStream`.

The stream contains the data when I do a [PostMan](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop/related?hl=enhttps://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) request however.

The difference is that PostMan makes a chunked data upload and RestAssured creates a multipart counterpart.

### Question

Is there a way to make a **chunked upload** request with RestAssured instead of a multipart one?

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question.

The solution is in [`RequestSpecification.body(File)`](http://static.javadoc.io/com.jayway.restassured/rest-assured/2.4.1/com/jayway/restassured/specification/RequestSpecification.html#body-java.io.File-). I must have overlooked the method before.

The test snippet should be corrected by replacing `multipart(File)` with `body(File)`:

```
given()
    .pathParam("imageTitle", "title")
    .body(getClass().getResourceAsStream("image.jpg"))
.when()
    .post("upload/{imageTitle}")
.then()
    .statusCode(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK)
```